# is there a tool to propagate preprocessor directives?

Tags: c#, preprocessor

Suppose I have the following class definition:

```
class foo
{
    #if bar
    private bool bar;
    #endif
    public void Do()
    {
        bar = false;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to propagate the preprocessor directive wrapping bar to every place where bar is used. The output should be something like this:

```
class foo
{
    #if bar
    private bool bar;
    #endif
    public void Do()
    {
        #if bar
        bar = false;
        #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Sean relatively common as a debug thing, IMO

Comment: @Sean Suppose I have the code of an application that has N features and I want to "automatically" find, for each feature, what are the fragments of code related to it. As an entry point I have some pieces of code that are already mapped to their corresponding features (using preprocessor directives). I need to propagate this information to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, basically. However, what you *can* do is split your code into two files and make use of `partial class` such that all your `bar` code is in one isolated file:

```cs
partial class foo
{
    partial void OnBar(bool value);
    public void Do()
    {
        OnBar(false);
    }
}
```

and

```cs
#if bar
partial class foo
{
    private bool bar;
    partial void OnBar(bool value)
    {
        bar = value;
    }
}
#endif
```

Now the *main* file knows nothing about `bar`. If the `bar` compilation symbol isn't defined, the `bar` field doesn't exist, and **nor does the `OnBar` method** - the method *and it's invocations* simply evaporate.

This can be useful in many scenarios, including additional levels of debugging code, or targeting multiple platforms / frameworks / operating systems (with specific files for different targets) - without your code being filled with `#if`.